# Cannot find setting to control unselected text background color for text editor

Tags: visual-studio-code

For some reason in the text editor pane, all lines containing characters have a background color that differs from the normal text editor background (i.e. they appear like they've been selected/highlighted with the cursor). I've tried switching themes, but doesn't seem to be controlled by any that I've tried. At a loss as to what setting might be controlling this. Any tips appreciated.

[With no lines selected (the problem)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dXBP.png)

[With a line selected (how it should look normally)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4o9P5.png)

Comment: Did you try to reset VSCode?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was caused by the SQLTools extension highlighting the code block. I uninstalled it for now, but it appears customizing the settings for that extension would also work.

Answer (score 0):

```
press ctrl + shift + p
type “settings json”
click “Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)
edit file and leave only braces { }
```

Resetting might help.